# Google Analytics (GA4) filter two events in Explorer

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have created a free form in the GA4 Explorer. My dimension is `Event name` and my Metrics is `Event count`.

[image]

**I want to filter two events only.**

I have tried to use regex, but it didn't get any results:

```
^(EventA|EventB)
```

How can I **filter two events** in Google Analytics explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually worked for me when I tried to filter for two events:

[image: Event Filter]

There's also another way to accomplish this. Instead of filtering the events, you can create a segment that specifies the two events:

1. Click the plus next to segments
2. Select Event Segment
3. Add a new condition: Events / Event Name
4. Click Or
5. Add a new condition: Events / Another Event Name